# How can I take a JSON List generated from an API and store that in a hashmap in Python?

Tags: python, api, html-table, hashmap

API: https://tda-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#current-quotes

Attempting to write the following code:

```
result = c.get_quote("TSLA")

stockdatalist = []

stockdatalist.append(result)

print(stockdatalist)
```

Output:

```
[<Response [200]>]
```

My Expectation:
How can I take the quote attributes and store them into a hashmap?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use a data structure like [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) to store the values like in a hashmap:

```
quote_dict = {}
stockdatadict = {}

for quote in quotes:
    result = c.get_quote(quote)
    stockdatadict[quote] = result
print(stockdatadict)
```